# Best configuration of my.cnf for make fast Magento navigation

Tags: mysql, mariadb, configuration, magento

I have a Magento 1.7 version site with 7000 configurable products. 
Site navigation is slow.
From the moment I click on a site link to when the address in the url bar changes several seconds pass.
Configuring the file `my.cnf` I have had improvements. But I think the configuration is not optimal.
What do you suggest to edit in my `my.cnf` file considering that I have a VPS with the following features?

```
CPU: ten cores
Intel® Xeon® E5-2620v3, E5-2630v4 or 4114 processor
50 GB RAM (guaranteed)
1200 GB disk space (100% SSD)
100% SSD disk space
UNLIMITED traffic!
1 Gbit / s port
DDoS protection (details)
```

This is `my.cnf` configuration:

```
#query_cache_size = 50G
#table_open_cache = 2000
#innodb_adaptive_flushing = 0
#innodb_adaptive_hash_index = 0
#innodb_autoextend_increment = 1000
#innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 64
#innodb-defragment=1
open_files_limit = 2000
innodb_io_capacity = 2000
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5G
innodb_thread_concurrency = 20
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
thread_concurrency = 30
table_open_cache = 2000
thread_cache_size = 32
#table_cache = 2000
query_cache_size = 30M
query_cache_limit = 1G
join_buffer_size = 3G
tmp_table_size = 2G
key_buffer = 70M
innodb_autoextend_increment=512
max_allowed_packet = 1G
max_heap_table_size = 1G
read_buffer_size = 50M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 50M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 50M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 50M
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 10G
#myisam_max_extra_sort_file_size = 5
myisam_repair_threads = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

`innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5G` --> change to 70% of *available* RAM (after excluding other apps)

`tmp_table_size = 2G` --> only `500M`

But... Neither of these is likely to solve the problem you pose.

You "can't configure away a performance problem".  Instead, you must provide the slow queries and the schema (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`).  The solution may be as simple as adding a suitable composite index.